# Como chamar uma classe pelo clique do botão

Tags: php

eu tenho uma classe em php que acessa o banco de dados para checar se o usuario é cadastrado, eu queria que quando eu clicar no botao "Entrar" que essa classe fosse chamada, eu vi alguns topicos relacionados mas estavam confusos, e nao me ajudaram!
E outra duvida eu teria que usar Jquery, PHP ou Javascript, qual seria a mais fácil e pratica?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acredito que uma linguagem `client-side` é mais fácil e prática...

exemplo:

```
<input type="button" name="button_name" onclick="exemploF()" value="Chama class">
```

**Jquery**

```
function exemploF() {
      $.post( 
          'exemplo.php'
       ).success(function(resp){
            json = $.parseJSON(resp);
            alert(json);
       });
}
```

**exemplo.php**

```
$class = new suaClass();
$method =  $class->umaFunction();
echo json_encode($method);
```